# How to make a get http request with oatpp (c++)

Tags: c++, http, oat++

I am new to using http request and cpp programming so do not hesitate to report any approximations about what I am saying.
I have a python server that runs in local at the address "http://127.0.0.1:8000/info" where if I open my navigator at this address, I display "Hello World".
I would like to make a cpp server that can get this "Hello World" string from this address (or any messages I would write instead) and show it back at another address "http://127.0.0.1:8080".
I have the following code that compiles using oatpp to generate my server :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "oatpp/core/Types.hpp"
#include "oatpp/web/server/HttpConnectionHandler.hpp"
#include "oatpp/network/tcp/server/ConnectionProvider.hpp"
#include "oatpp/network/ConnectionProvider.hpp"
#include "oatpp/network/Server.hpp"
#include "oatpp/parser/json/mapping/ObjectMapper.hpp"
#include "oatpp/core/macro/codegen.hpp"

#include OATPP_CODEGEN_BEGIN(ApiController) // Beginning of code generation for API controller

class MyController : public oatpp::web::server::api::ApiController {
public:
    MyController(const std::shared_ptr<ObjectMapper>& objectMapper)
        : oatpp::web::server::api::ApiController(objectMapper) {}

    ENDPOINT("GET", "/", root) {
        auto resp = "Hello, World!";
        auto response = createResponse(Status::CODE_200, resp);
        return response;
    }
};

#include OATPP_CODEGEN_END(ApiController) // End of code generation for API controller

void run() {
    oatpp::base::Environment env;

    // Create a HTTP connexion provider
    auto connectionProvider = oatpp::network::tcp::server::ConnectionProvider::createShared({"localhost", 8080});

    auto objectMapper = oatpp::parser::json::mapping::ObjectMapper::createShared();

    // Create the HTTP router for server requests
    auto router = oatpp::web::server::HttpRouter::createShared();
    
    // Add controller to the router
    router->addController(std::make_shared<MyController>(objectMapper));

    // Create a handler for HTTP connexion
    auto connectionHandler = oatpp::web::server::HttpConnectionHandler::createShared(router);

    // Create HTTP server
    oatpp::network::Server server(connectionProvider, connectionHandler);

    // Start server
    std::cout << "Server started on port 8080" << std::endl;
    server.run();
}

int main() {
    
    run();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I am trying to code a GET request from my first python server and cout the resulting string from this request, but I cannot find a way to make it work. This is my current code :

```
#include "oatpp/web/client/HttpRequestExecutor.hpp"
#include "oatpp/network/tcp/client/ConnectionProvider.hpp"

// Make a http request to get data
auto connectionProvider = oatpp::network::tcp::client::ConnectionProvider::createShared({"http://127.0.0.1:8000/platform/battery/getInfoBattery", 8000});
auto requestExecutor    = oatpp::web::client::HttpRequestExecutor::createShared(connectionProvider);
auto headers            = oatpp::web::protocol::http::Protocol::Headers::createShared();
headers->put("user-agent", "super-agent");
auto response = requestExecutor->executeOnce("GET", "/endpoint", headers, nullptr);
std::cout << response->readBodyToString->c_str() << std::endl;
```

This code is based on the [github of oatpp about HTTP GET request](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp-examples/issues/3) but needs to be updated as I am using oatpp-1.3.0 where oatpp::web::protocol::http::Protocol::Headers::createShared() does not exist anymore (it might be deprecated). Do you know how can I make it work ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Not sure if I understood. You want to do the GET request with the following URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, and you want your cpp server to handle this request by sending another GET request to URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/info`, then return the data returned by that 2nd GET request? How do you want to handle 2 different servers listening on the same address and port? And why not just modify your python server to give the sam results on both URLs?